# Adding section (with sub elements) to HTML using a Javascript list (with the ability to edit later on)

Tags: javascript, html

tl;dr I want to understand how to be able to add sections to the DOM from a list of unknown length with the ability to reference the value of each element in a section later on.

I'm developing an application for a school submission and am having some trouble with the GUI. It uses an MVC Framework with the Model being SQL, the View being HTML, CSS, and JS, and the Controller being Python (with JS as a translator).

My problem is that I'm sending a list of data to the frontend from python that contains a bunch of information relating to a certain client. This information includes the client themselves and their family members. I need to be able to build the front end with each of those family members (of an unknown number) with the ability to reference each block of data if they're edited by the user (and thus sent back to Python so it can be committed into the database).

I have no clue how to approach this and I haven't been able to find anything (I don't know what to search for) on how to add sections of elements to HTML with the ability to reference each element later on.

[Here's an image of what I want to do (I don't have enough points to put it directly into the post)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKn4p.png)

And here's an outline of what I want to be able to do in code (I'm not great at webtech and came up with a basic example)

```js
/*Something along these lines (I'm not great at javascript or much of webtech at all to be honest, so bear with me please)*/
function buildFamily (data) {
  for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
    var button_data = data[i][0];
    /*Code to add element*/
    document.getElementById(/*The element id*/).value = button_data;
  }
}

function editFamily (data, familyIndex) {
  for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
    document.getElementById(/*FamilyList[familyIndex][i]*/).value = data[i];
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <section id="root-client">
      <button id="root-client-example">
        example root client
      </button>
    </section>
    <hr>
    <!--How do I add and remove the following - note that the ID tags are just examples-->
    
    <section id="family-member-1">
      <button id="family-member-example-1">
        example family member 1
      </button>
    </section>
    <hr>
    
    <section id="family-member-2">
      <button id="family-member-example-2">
        example family member 2
      </button>
    </section>
    <hr>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

I really just want to understand how to be able to add sections to the DOM from a list of unknown length with the ability to reference the value of each element in a section later on. I don't have any code, as I don't really know where to start - you don't have to give me the entire example of the image, just a basic understanding of how to add *n* number of elements via javascript.

Thank you for any and all help, and again, I apologize for the un-neat code and lack of a lot of information - I tried to make it better after my last question (but it still isn't great).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
const users = document.querySelector('.users'); // Container in which user data is shown

let memberElements = [];

function buildFamily(family) {
  // Data is array
  for(const member of family) { // Loop each user
    let memberElement = document.createElement('section'); // Create section
    memberElement.classList.add('user'); // Add class `user` to it
    // Set here some properties for element
    memberElement.textContent = member; // Demo.
    // ...
    users.appendChild(memberElement); // Insert it into DOM
    
    memberElements.push(memberElement); // Save link to element
  }
}

function updateFamily(family, index) {
  let element = memberElements[index]; // Get element for member
  // Do some changes
  element.textContent = family[index]; // Demo
}

// Demo
let family = ['Member 1', 'Demo member 2'];
buildFamily(family);

family[1] = 'Edited member'; // Update data
updateFamily(family, 1)
```

```html
<main class="users">
   <!-- User data will be added here -->
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is pretty much what I needed. However, I have a small follow-up, how would I drop these elements from the DOM if I need to? Moreover, I a novice in js, what's the difference between const and var in this situation (all I understand is var is function scoped and const if local scoped). Again, thanks for your help.